# What is the easiest way to integrate Outlook web add-in into an existing ASP.NET Core 6 application?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, outlook, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application with a Rest API to another server application and would like to integrate a outlook web add in into the Rest API application.

Is there any existing template or example to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider your Outlook web add-in as a regular web application where you could call any REST API endpoint. See [Add-in Command Demo add-in](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo) sample code for samples.

Don't forget to address CORS issues, see [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) for more information.